# Can Earthling uses Latena

Tags: cop-craft

In the first episode in the anime it is stated that Kei's handgund poses a low amount Latena.

> On episode 4 this fact was strenghtened as his weapon move automatically and aids him on targetting a spell caster.

Is it possible for people from earth to use Latena? Does the novel eventually explore the possibility?